# error after installing the package ("tseries")

Tags: r

> Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘tseries’ in
>   loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck =
>   vI[[j]]):  there is no package called ‘quadprog’ In addition: Warning
>   message: package ‘tseries’ was built under R version 3.5.3

This is the error I am receiving.

Comment: Did you tried to install 'quadprog' package and then load 'tseries' again ?

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: I am unable to load tseries package after installing it sucessfully.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
install.packages("tseries", dependencies = TRUE)
```

If that does not work try this:

```
install.packages("tseries", repos=c("http://rstudio.org/_packages", "http://cran.rstudio.com"))
```

Comment: Installation has been done sucessfully, yet I am unable to load it.                      
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘tseries’:
 object 'as.timeSeries' not found whilst loading namespace 'xts'
In addition: Warning message:
package ‘tseries’ was built under R version 3.5.3